# How to set variable

Tags: shell, scripting

I have date in format yyyy-mm-dd and want to save in a variable to use later in my script. I can get right format but not sure how to store in variable mydate

Comment: `mydate="2017-12-31"`

Comment: But I have that value in a file from commands

Comment: It's in a _file_?  Or you're getting it as the output of a command?  `mydate="$(cat /path/to/file)"` if it's actually in a file; `mydate="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"` (for example) if it's from a command.

Comment: Send -e 's/\//-/g' file1.txt | cut -c5-14 > file2.txt

Comment: Then I want it in variable mydate

Comment: Word send above is sed

Answer (score 2):

As [DopeGhoti commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349777/how-to-set-variable#comment619124_349777), for non-csh shells:

```
mydate="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

(Seeing your later edits to the Q): if the date is instead inside of file2.txt, then:

```
mydate="$(<file2.txt)"
```